# Как сделать элемент формы "счетчик" с кнопками больше меньше?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать кнопку такого вида? Есть ли такой стандартный элемент формы для выбора?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Тот элемент, что вы продемонстрировали не есть счётчик. Это Select-бокс. Именно счётчика нет, а вот указанный, товарищем [[@эмиль](/users/3025/%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/3025/%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), элемент - будет работать только в Chrome. Вы можете воспользоваться ряшечками JQuery-UI. Если не изменяет память там есть такой элемент.
Или используйте `<input type="range" />` Он хотя бы поддерживается 3 из 4 мажорных.
Если хотите конечно, вы можете написать ручками на JS. Допустим так:

```
<form>
     <input type=text id=month value="Январь" style="height:30px;"/>
     <input type=hidden id=incdec value=0 />
     <input type=button id=inc value=ˆ style="margin-left:-35px;max-height:15px;margin-top:-15px" onclick="var monthYear = ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь']; if(this.form.incdec.value<11){this.form.incdec.value++;this.form.month.value = monthYear[this.form.incdec.value];}">
     <input type=button id=dec value=ˇ style="margin-left:-32px;max-height:15px;margin-top:15px" onclick="var monthYear = ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь']; if(this.form.incdec.value>0){this.form.incdec.value--;this.form.month.value = monthYear[this.form.incdec.value];}">
</form>
```

Остаётся добавить проверку ввода.

Comment: Ну может и не счетчик, а селект. Главное чтобы как на картинке было, выбор месяца путем нажатия стрелок вверх-вниз.

Comment: @nMike, код исправил. Правда слишком толсто ;]. Лучше вынести из контекста формы это

Answer (score 1):

```html
<select size="1" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='number'>
```

Это из HTML5. 
Правда тут только числа. Так что можно использовать числа вместо месяц 1..12.
Чтобы не вводились другие значения, задаете параметры max и min.

Так же советую прочитать [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/type)

Answer (score 0):

Обычный спинер дж квери, только вместо цифр подставляешь из масива месяцы.

[Спинер](https://github.com/btburnett3/jquery.ui.spinner)

```
$("#myinput")
.spinner({min: 0, max: 11, increment: 1})
.on('change', function(){
   var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10),
       arrMonth = ['январь', 'февраль'];

   $(this).val(arrMonth[val]);
});
```